# ng-click is not working with any of my divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple un-ordered list populated with ng-repeat and I want something to happen every time a user clicks on one of the list items. However, ng-click doesn't seem to be working with any of the divs inside my html, it only works with buttons. At first I thought the issue would be with the ng-repeat but it turns out that even outside of the ng-repeat ng-click does not seem to work. I have tried using ng-mousedown as well, and it doesn't seem to be working either.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="noteItem" ng-mouseleave="btnShow = false" ng-mouseenter="btnShow = true" ng-click="alert('click');">
    <li>
        {{note.subject|removeHTML}}<a ng-show="btnShow" ng-click="deleteNote(note._id)"><i>DELETE</i></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

I have tried wrapping another div outside of this div as well but it still didn't work. I have been stuck on this problem for about an hour now.

Comment: Show us the controller where you define the funcion `deleteNote`. Also you can try to specify an empty href. Take a look to: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: If you're expecting your `alert('click')` to show an alert, then you might be wrong. Only way it will do so is if you define a `$scope.alert` function to trigger the alert

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid, thank you for that. It has been a long night...

Answer (score 0):

You have ng-click in div and also in `<a>` element, the one being executed is in the `<a>` element not the ng-click in div.

Try to add div like this and try to click.

```
<div ng-click="yourScopeMethodHere()">click me</div>
```

BTW, directly calling JS alert() in ng-click will not work.

Answer (score 0):

When the ng click get executed it looks for scope function and expressions. alerts and console logs neither of it so it won't get executed like this. What you can do is create a scope function and call the alert inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a `ng-click` on the parent element (`<div>`) as well, the click will be **triggered on both**. You can cancel parent `ng-click` on the child with `$event.stopPropagation()`.

```
<div ng-mouseleave="btnShow = false" ng-mouseenter="btnShow = true" ng-click="alert('click');">
    <li>
        {{note.subject|removeHTML}}
        <a ng-show="btnShow" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); deleteNote(note._id)"><i>DELETE</i></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

As a side note, `ng-click="alert('click')` will seek for `$scope.alert()`, if you are hoping to open the JavaScript basic alert... ;-)